# starting tshark with python - invalid command

Tags: python, popen, tshark

I'm trying to start tshark with python. Testing the command in command line seems to be OK. but while starting it with python, I'm getting error as described below.

Any idea what is going wrong?

```
cmd1='"tshark -i 1 -Y "ssdp" -T fields -E separator=, -E header=y -e ip.id -e ip.checksum"'
cmd=shlex.split(cmd1)

try:
    tsharkProc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                                  shell=True,
                                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                  executable="C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\tshark.exe")
except:
    print("ERROR {} while running {}".format(sys.exc_info()[1], cmd))
```

And the error:

> Capturing on 'Ethernet 2' tshark: Invalid capture filter "/c tshark -i
> 1 -Y ssdp -T fields -E separator=, -E header=y -e ip.id -e
> ip.checksum" for interface 'Ethernet 2'.
>
> That string isn't a valid capture filter (can't parse filter
> expression: syntax error). See the User's Guide for a description of
> the capture filter syntax. 0 packets captured

Comment: so how shall I pass the filter to tshark?

Comment: I've updated to `cmd= ["tshark", "-i", "1", "-Y ssdp", "-F", "k12text", "-T", "fields", "-E", "header=y", "-E", "separator=,", "-e", "ip.checksum",  "-e", "ip.id"]`

I'm not getting the error, but I'm not getting the output as well

`while True:`
    `output = tsharkProc.stdout.readline()`
`if output:`
        `print(output.strip().decode())`

Comment: OK, seems that there is some output, but with a huge delay